# Scikit: Convert one-hot encoding to encoding with integers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I need to convert one-hot encoding to categories represented by unique integers. So one-hot encoding created with the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
labels = [[1],[2],[3]]
enc.fit(labels)  
for x in [1,2,3]:
    print(enc.transform([[x]]).toarray())

Out:
[[ 1.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Could be converted back to a set of unique integers, for example:

[1,2,3] or [11,37, 45] or any other where each integer uniquely represents a single class.

Is it possible to do with scikit-learn or any other python lib?

*** Update ***

Tried to:

```
labels = [[1],[2],[3], [4], [5],[6],[7]]
enc.fit(labels) 

lst = []
for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
    lst.append(enc.transform([[x]]).toarray())
lst
Out:
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])]


a = np.array(lst)
np.where(a==1)[1]
Out:
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Not what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using `np.where` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
np.where(a==1)[1]
```

This prints `array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)`. This works since `np.where(a==1)[1]` returns the column indices of the `1`'s, which are exactly the labels.

In addition, since `a` is a `0,1`-matrix, you can also replace `np.where(a==1)[1]` with just `np.where(a)[1]`.

**Update**: The following solution should work with your format:

```
l=[np.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
 np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])]
a=np.array(l)

np.where(a)[2]
```

This prints

```
array([0, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Alternativaly, you could use the original solution together with @ml4294's comment.

Comment: Does not work for other array length. Please see my updated question

Comment: You constructed a list of (in fact) one-dimensional arrays, not a two-dimensional numpy array.

Comment: @dokondr If you simply use `lst = enc.transform(labels).toarray()` instead of the for loop, you should have no problems with either of the two solutions.

Comment: @Miriam Farber Thanks.It works, but I can't grasp `np.where(a)[2]` magic (( Why 2 ?

Comment: @dokondr the 2 is because in your representation `a` is a 3D array, and you are interested in the columns, which now form the third dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.argmax()`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

enc = OneHotEncoder()
labels = [[1],[2],[3]]
enc.fit(labels)  
x = enc.transform(labels).toarray()


# x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
xr = (np.argmax(x, axis=1)+1).reshape(-1, 1)
print(xr)
```

This should return `array([[1], [2], [3]])`. If you want instead `array([[0], [1], [2]])`, just remove the `+1` in the definition of `xr`.

Comment: This (xr = (np.argmax(x, axis=1)+1).reshape(-1, 1)) returns a list : [[1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1] ....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to 'encode' the data, you can use its `.inverse_transform()` method to 'decode' the data (I think this requires `.__version__ = 0.20.1` or newer):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
labels = [[1],[2],[3]]
encoder = enc.fit(labels)
encoded_labels = encoder.transform(labels)
decoded_labels = encoder.inverse_transform(encoded_labels)
decoded_labels # array([[1],
                        [2],
                        [3]])
```

n.b. decoded_labels is a numpy array not a list.

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.inverse_transform